# Joomla output override not working on production server

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have a local installation of my joomla site and everything works fine and then procceded to migrate to production with no problems. I had to change something within one of my output overrides for virtuemart module and when the changes where done in local files I uploaded to production ftp and then I get a white page of doom.

When turning on error reporting I get:

```
 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/cyclo2.com/public_html/templates/cyclo/html/mod_virtuemart_cart/default.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/cyclo2.com/public_html/modules/mod_virtuemart_cart/mod_virtuemart_cart.php on line 61
```

Line 61 is simply

```
require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_virtuemart_cart'));
```

But this file that I had in my template folder was working well before the changes! I tried to revert to the old file and still the same blank page issue. It seems it was doing the override correctly and then it decided it didn't want to anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a permissions issue, I found out that default.php had permissions set to 600. How it got changed, I don't know, but setting it to 755 made everything work again.